# Is the notation of the "routePartitionName" element in this XML Diagram correct?

Tags: xml, xsd

[image]

So as per [XML Schema definition](http://taf-jsg.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Annex_6.1_XSD_Diagram_Notations.pdf), the three lines in the top left of the box of "routePartitionName" indicate that it is the last element, so it has no child items.

However, as you can see by the "+" in the first diagram, and by the axlapi:XFkType yellowish box in the second, it does have child items. I dont understand how this adds up, are the diagramms wrong, or is there something i dont understand about XML Schema syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The document that you are referring to is not an official standard, and the notation is specific to one product.

I think this is the paragraph that you are referring to:

> > This lines symbol on the top left corner of  element  rectangle  indicates  this  is  the  simple  type  in  technical  term.  We  can  say  this  element  does  not  have  any
> > child  elements  and  is  the  last  element.

It is not an accurate description. The symbol indicates that the type of element is simple - there are no child *tags*. Note that some simple elements are allowed to have *attributes*, though.